# R's as.POSIXct function gives NA, 30+ formats tested, time includes AM/PM

Tags: r, datetime, statistics

I'm trying to convert the following date/time string to an POSIXct object:

```
19 Aug 2015 11:34 am
```

I tried 30+ approaches. Still getting NAs.

Here's the list of scripts that didn't work (just 4 examples):

```
as.POSIXct(toupper("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am"), format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
as.POSIXct(toupper("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am"), format = "%d %B %Y %I:%M %P")
as.POSIXct("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am", format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
as.POSIXct(toupper("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am"), tz = "UTC", format = '%d %b %Y %I:%M %p')
```

etc. Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in English, try:

```
as.POSIXct("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am", format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
```

If not, try:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
as.POSIXct("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am", format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
```

Explanation: `strptime` is the formatting function used to change into POSIXct, and it uses the month names from your locale, as found in `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")`. If you give English names for months, you won't get a match if your locale is not English.

Comment: works for me! what is the output of `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")`? The month variable works in your local langague, if you aren;t set for english that might be your problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `toupper` is that it also uppercases your month, which doesn't fit the standard. But you can use regular expressions to target the am/pm bit more precisely:

```
yourtime <- c("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am", "19 Aug 2015 11:34 pm")

# Regular expressions to the rescue!
y <- sub(pattern = "(am|pm)", replacement = "\\U\\1", x = yourtime, perl = TRUE)

# Just AM and PM have been capitalized
y

# No problems, now
as.POSIXct(y, format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
```

Answer (score -1):

First set locale and then try conversion:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.POSIXct("19 Aug 2015 11:34 am", format = "%d %b %Y %I:%M %p")
```